# Getting NaN output in C#

Tags: c#, nan

I'm trying to get a simple result on a console app in C#

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
x=(7*x/4+1/2) - (5*x/4+1/2)*Math.Acos(Math.PI*x);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

This is resulting in NaN, and I can't figure out why. I'm not very programming savvy, so I'm sure its something obvious. Thanks!

---

EDIT: It should have been Math.Cos, not Math.Acos. Now I have come across something else, when I input say x=3, it returns a result of 9; however, [it should result in 10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%287%2ax%2F4%2B1%2F2%29+-+%285%2ax%2F4%2B1%2F2%29%2acos%28PI%2ax%29+for+x%3D3). Any reason as to why?

Comment: You can only take the arccos of a number between -1 and 1, I believe.  So you have to ensure that `(Math.PI*x)` is going to result in a number between -1 and 1.

Comment: If you have a second question *pleaes start a new question*. One question per question!

Comment: Also, you will find your program easier to debug if you do not destroy your data as you go. Say `double result = (7... Console.WriteLine(result);` rather than destroying the value of `x`.  Variables are cheap; make lots of them.

Comment: Here's a hint: what if you said `(7.0 * x / 4.0 + 1.0 / 2.0 )...` and so on. Then do you get the right answer?  Do you see why there is a difference? `1/2` is zero, `1.0/2.0` is `0.5`. C# does integer arithmetic **in integers**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`Math.Acos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.acos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can only take inputs between -1 and +1. When you put in Pi, it returns NaN, which then breaks the whole formula. You probably wanted simply [`Math.Cos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

On getting the wrong answer, it's probably integer division on the `1/2`. When dividing integers, the answer is truncated, so `1/2` results in `0`, not the expected `0.5`, thus giving you an answer off by 1. Try it with `1.0/2.0`

Comment: Ah great! Does that only happen on 1/2, 2/4, etc.?

Comment: It will happen anytime you try to divide integers, be it variables or constants (as above). It's something that comes up a lot and needs to be dealt with.

Answer (score 3):

Start by splitting it up.  once you get a NaN, all math after that is a NaN!

You have to check for NaN using `isNaN`, because `x == NaN` is **always false**!

Comment: Definitely should have been Cos, not Acos. But, now I'm getting incorrect values (see edit). Anything you notice?

Answer (score 1):

As good practice, you should also check that the text input by the user is actually a number. You can use `double.TryParse`, which returns false if the text cannot be parsed as a number. Your current code will throw an exception instead

Answer (score 0):

Arccos pi = "the angle whose cosine is pi".  Cosines are only ever in the range -1 to +1.